# Accordion for UIView and SubViews in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, accordion

I'm trying to build an accordion style ( expand/collapse ) list in IOS/Swift 3. Was confused on which approach to follow like a static UITableView ( since my sub divisions have different types of Ui Controls in the cells ie some have checkbox ,spinner, textview etc. with labels to show configure a list of different Valves) , UIView with nested UIViews sections with an option to clip views . But both have been messed up with without any success.

Illustration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL6WH.jpg

Below are the links I followed

https://github.com/justinmfischer/SwiftyAccordionCells

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-static-table-view-storyboard/

https://github.com/Weebly/TableSchemer

https://github.com/Alliants/ALAccordion

Any other approach without UITableView?

Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Static vs dynamic table will depend on your data source.  Does your data source for your table change?  If so you'll want a dynamic table, if not then you can design it out in a static one.

As for the accordion feature, what I've done in the past is to add a tap gesture recognizer to the header view of each section.  When the tap is detected I change my datasource and reload the table view.  What happens is that number of rows for section is called on reload, and I return 0 so that none of the rows show.  When tapped again you can go back to showing the normal number of rows.

To get the animation you need to use delete rows with index paths and animate it.

Comment: thanks . My datasource won't change ( number of rows for each section is fixed ) and each rows/sub sections have different types of design though.